# Vertical positioning of tikzcd environment

Tags: math-mode, tikz-cd

Can I write something like `\begin{tikzcd}[t]`(maths)`\end{tikzcd}`, as with `\begin{aligned}[t]`(maths)`{\end{aligned}` to get the `tikzcd` environment to position "top"? In the example below, I want the `\implies` to be in line with the `\int`.

**Edit:** for reasons which I won't bother describing unless it seems relevant, it's convenient for me to keep the `\implies` sign in the parent environment in which the `tikzcd` environment is nested.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, bm, tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \implies 
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep = small, ampersand replacement = \&]
        \int g \text{d}t \arrow[r, equals] \arrow[d, equals] \& \int \bm{\Ddot{x}} \arrow[d, equals] \\
        gt \arrow[r, equals] \& \bm{\Ddot{x}} + c
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly than you after the following  commutative diagram:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
\ar[r,Rightarrow]   & \int g\,\mathrm{d}t  
                      \ar[r, equal] 
                      \ar[d, equal]  & \int \ddot{x}\,\mathrm{d}t
                                      \ar[d, equal]    \\  
                    & gt
                      \ar[r, equal] & \ddot{x} + c     
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Now, that you edit your question it seems, that you looking for something like the following:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=3.141591]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, bm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
\begin{tikzcd}[baseline=-1em, anchor=north, % <---
                    column sep = small, ampersand replacement = \&]
\ar[r,Rightarrow]   \& \int g\, dt
                      \ar[r, equal]
                      \ar[d, equal]  \& \int \ddot{x}\, dt
                                      \ar[d, equal]    \\
                    \& gt
                      \ar[r, equal] \& \ddot{x} + c
\end{tikzcd}
    & = some\ math\ expression     \\
c^2 & = a^2 + b^2
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=3.141591]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, bm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
\implies    &   \begin{tikzcd}[baseline=-1em, anchor=north,
                                    column sep = small, ampersand replacement = \&]
                \int g\, dt
                \ar[r, equal]
                \ar[d, equal]  \& \int \ddot{x}\, dt
                                  \ar[d, equal]    \\
                 gt
                 \ar[r, equal] \& \ddot{x} + c
                \end{tikzcd}     \\
c^2  ={} & a^2 + b^2
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. This makes sense for the example as stated. I've edited the OP to add that it's convenient for me to have the ```\implies``` in the environment containing the ```tikzcd``` environment rather than in the ```tikzcd``` environment itself. Do you know if alignment can be achieved with that constraint?

Comment: @mjc, sorry, but now your question is unclear. Please edit it and explain what is your problem. The best with  MWE, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: @mjc, see addendum in answer.

Comment: The ```anchor``` and ```baseline``` commands are what I was looking for. Thanks.